# How to implement simulated annealing to find longest path in graph

Tags: pseudocode, simulated-annealing, longest-path

I've found a piece of pseudocode which explains simulated annealing for longest path problem, but there are a few details which I do not understand.

Currently I have implemented a structure representing graph, and method to generate random graph and random path in the graph - both uniform.

Here's the pseudocode of simulated annealing:

```
Procedure Anneal(G, s, t, P)
P = RandomPath(s, t, G)
temp = TEMP0
itermax = ITER0
while temp > TEMPF do
  while iteration  < itermax do
    S = RandomNeighbor(P, G)
    delta = S.len - P.len
    if delta > 0 then
       P = S
    else
      x = random01
      if x < exp(delta / temp) then
        P = S
      endif
    endif
    iteration = iteration + 1
  enddo
  temp = Alpha(temp)
  itermax = Beta(itermax)
enddo
```

The details which I do not find clear enough to understand are:

**RandomNeighbor(P, G)**

**Alpha(temp)**

**itermax = Beta(itermax)**

What are these methods supposed to do ?

Comment: Do you have a link of where you found it?

Comment: Here is the file which I referred to : http://www.scholvin.com/thesis.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RandomNeighbor(P, G)**: This is probably the function that creates a new solution (or new neighboring solution) from your current solution (the neighbor is chosen randomly).

**Alpha(temp)**: That's the function that reduces the temperature (probably `temp *= alpha`)

**itermax = Beta(itermax)**: I can only assume that this one is changing (most probably, resetting) the counter on iterations since it's being used on the inner `while`. So, when your counter for iteration reaches its max, it's reset.